# Grails Command Object not getting Bound

Tags: grails

I am doing a POC for Command object in Grails Controller and i face a road block where the binding doesn't happen.

**Command Object**

```
public class Employee {

    String name;

    int age;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
class EmployeeController {

    def index() {

        render (" Employee Index Called ");
    }

    def emp(Employee employee){

        println( employee.toString());
        render(" Success");

    }
}
```

I am calling **emp** action from a rest client as below

**Method: POST**

**URL** : http://localhost:8080/Grails/employee/emp

**Request Body** : **{     "name": "Vinod",     "age": 34 }**

I get employee.name as null and employee.age=0 always

I am suspecting my Request Body is wrong but not sure. Please help where I am going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: are you sending JSON?

Comment: For Testing i try to convert Java Object To JSON and call the service from Rest Client passing this JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For POST request method, I had to set  'Content-Type' header as 'application/json'

Grails constructs command object from JSON in request body of POST(JSON to Java Object)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, json is not bound automatically to command object (defined as action method arg), only plain `params` are. To get a hold on JSON request you have to call

```
def json = request.JSON
```

and then you can try binding it to your object:

```
def co = new MyCommandObject( json )
```

Answer (score -1):

Whenever Grails finds 'Content-Type' header as 'application/json' it will automatically parse the request body in JSON to command object and pass it on to the controller method.

You may also want to make the command class validatable by doing the following.
In Grails 3:
Your command class can to implement grails.validation.Validateable trait.

```
import grails.validation.Validateable

class Employee implements Validateable{
    String name
    int age
}
```

In Grails 2.x:
You command class can have grails.validation.Validateable annotation

```
@grails.validation.Validateable
class Employee implements Validateable{
    String name
    int age
}
```

Comment: I believe from Docs, @grails.validation.Validateable is optional and it just gives warning. Lines from Docs "It is not required that command object classes be validateable."

Comment: You are right. Then your request body is not recognised as JSON. Are you setting the 'Content-Type' header as 'application/json'?

Comment: It worked. I was missing 'Content-Type' header as 'application/json'. You may edit your answer or add a new answer so that I can accept it.